# Moving Python script 10.3 to Pro. How do I know the script ran in Pro and not 10.3?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, idle

I have inherited a Python script that mosaics many files in 10.3. I normally run using IDLE outside 10.3.

I don't code at all but am trying to learn so I can move the code to ArcGIS Pro to ensure we stay up to date. I have learned to convert what I have from python 2.7 to 3.6 successfully.

Based on what I have read it is better to run code outside of Pro to speed processes up if there is no need to have GIS open. Therefore I am wanting to run the code as such.

I have read as much as I can comprehend on conda environment and running the script through a .bat file. However if I simply go to my code and right click I have the option of: Edit with Idle, Edit with Idle (Pro) and Run with ArcGIS Pro. If I choose Edit with Idle (Pro) to open the script and click run, the process runs fine.

Did it run via Pro?

How would I know other than what I right clicked to start the process has the word Pro in it?

Does this mean I can skip the whole conda or .bat usage (both were giving me errors on start up so I  hope so!)?

Comment: The `sys` class can tell you if you're using Python 2.7 or 3.x (see `sys.version_info`)

Comment: Thank you! For sake of me understanding further -  Could I ever be using python 3.x and it still use 10.3? Sounds like based on your response IF I am using python 3.x, it would not be able to even use Arcgis 10.x processes- Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. There are Python3 environments for ArcGIS Server 10.x, but all Python3 environments use ArcGIS Pro classes.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of IDLE you should see  *Python 3.6.10 | Anaconda, Inc.* on the first line.

If you need further proof you could, In IDLE, at the command line enter:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

This will return a Python List and you can see which interpreter is being called.

```
['', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib\\site-packages\\future-0.18.2-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2019.3-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32security', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\lib\\site-packages\\sympy-1.5.1-py3.6.egg']
```

Comment: My Idle had my .py name/path followed by 3.6 at the top bar. Running your suggested command lines did provide a long list of data all of which pointed to Pro- thank you so very much!